# Can't quit the Java JVM

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

I've written a simple Java program. First I add the component to the class extends the JWindow, then show.

```
public class G4TestWindow extends JWindow {

    public G4TestWindow(){
        JLabel hah=new JLabel("Wooh");
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(hah);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

and launch in the main class.

```
public class G4Test extends JWindow {

    public static void main(String []args){
        G4TestWindow g4tw=new G4TestWindow();   
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

But it can't quit from the java JVM even if I use `System.exit(-1)`.
I find that the reason is `genContentPane().add(hah)` after many tries (if I leave this out, the JVM exits normally).

Why is this?

Comment: Are you sure the line calling `System.exit` is reached?

Comment: When I run your code, it exits for me, no problem. As per the excellent question from @oldrinb, consider placing a `System.out.println("here")` or something similar just before you call to `System.exit(-1)` just to see if the lines are being reached.

Comment: It really reached <pre><code>System.exit(-1)</code></pre>.I find if G4Test extends the JFrame .It will quit normally.But the problem exits when the parent class is JWindow.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it fails.  It reaches the System.exit and exits on my system (JDK 1.6 on Mac), even with the ".add(hah).

However you are not using the BorderLayout layout manager correctly. When using BorderLayout, whenever you add a component, you need to specify the area, for example:

```
getContentPane().add(hah, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Try fixing this and see if you get better results.

Comment: Sorry, but that's guaranteed to have absolutely no effect on this current problem. I'm betting that there's an infinite loop somewhere or that he's calling a different main method. That's why @oldrinb's comment is so appropriate and in a nutshell summarizes about all anyone can say about the original poster's problem.